# What does altering a file/directory mean?

Tags: files, directory, ntfs

From `man ntfsundelete`

> Look for deleted files altered in the last two days
>
> ```
> ntfsundelete /dev/hda1 -t 2d
> ```

I wonder what altering  files/directories mean?

1. Does deleting some files/directories count as altering them?

   For example,
   if I created a file more than two days ago, and didn't change it
   until yesterday when I deleted. Will the command be able to recover
   it?
2. Does moving some files/directories from being under a directory to being under another directory
   count as altering them, even when the files/directories being moved
   have not been changed themselves?

I am hoping to find a way to specify and undelete the directories (with files inside) that I deleted at once last time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions in a different order. What does altering a file mean ?

Altering means whenever you modify and update the content of the file (modify in linux). If we look at *ntfsundelete* source code we can clearly see what the authors have marked as **alter**:

[ntfsundelete.h](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/NTFS-3G/ntfsprogs/ntfsundelete.h) line 72:

> ```
> time_t         date_a;    /*  altered */
> ```

[ntfsundelete.c](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/NTFS-3G/ntfsprogs/ntfsundelete.c) line 1002, 1045:

> ```
> name->date_a     = ntfs2timespec(attr->last_data_change_time).tv_sec;
> ```

last_data_change_time is also explained in [linux/fs/ntfs/inode.c](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/fs/ntfs/inode.c) line 674:

> ```
>       * mtime is the last change of the data within the file. Not changed
>       * when only metadata is changed, e.g. a rename doesn't affect mtime.
>       */
>       vi->i_mtime = ntfs2utc(si->last_data_change_time);
> ```

Question nr. 2:

List of actions that change a directory modification time:

[Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/27394/list-of-actions-that-change-a-directories-modification-time)

[Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648)

Question nr.1:

No, deleting a file does not count as altering it. So if you created a file more than two days ago and didn't change it until yesterday when you deleted it the command won't be able to recover it.

Here is a test on my NTFS partition. I had three .jpg files with mtime as follows:

- brr.jpg 2012-05-21
- IMG_2001.JPG 2012-05-21
- s640x480.jpg 2011-03-18

I modified IMG_2001.JPG with MSPaint and saved it so modification time changed to today: 2012-08-26. I then deleted (SHIF+DELETE) all three files and rebooted in Linux.

Running *ntfsundelete* without *--time* switch (altered time not taken into account) prints out a long list of files starting with the above three files:

```
ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 -m '*.jpg'

Inode    Flags  %age  Date           Size  Filename
---------------------------------------------------------------
72801    FN..   100%  2012-05-21   1055334  brr.JPG
72822    FN..   100%  2012-08-26   1034072  IMG_2001.JPG
72826    FN..   100%  2011-03-18     52333  s640x480.jpg
.....    ....   ....  ..........   .......  ............

Files with potentially recoverable content: 1631
```

Running *ntfsundelete* with *--time d1* switch (so for files altered in the last 1 day) prints out only one file, namely the one I have just modified before deleting all three of them:

```
ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 -m '*.jpg' -t 1d

Inode    Flags  %age  Date           Size  Filename
---------------------------------------------------------------
72822    FN..   100%  2012-08-26   1034072  IMG_2001.JPG

Files with potentially recoverable content: 1
```